# Add values to specific rows and columns in pandas df

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, nested

I'm trying to add values on a pandas dataframe based on the inputs of a user and an agent. This is an example that I am working so far.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import random

ls = np.zeros((9,3))

choices = ['R','P','S']
df = pd.DataFrame(ls, columns=['R','P','S'], index = ['RR','RP','RS','PR','PP','PS','SR','SP','SS'])

for _ in range(100):
 user_choice = random.choice(choices)
 agent_choice = random.choice(choices)
 #print(user_choice,agent_choice)

 for _ in range(len(df)):
  for _ in range(len(df['R'])):
   df[user_choice + agent_choice][agent_choice] += 1
```

Desired result will look something like:

[image]

Any help will be much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure this is really what you want, but Python, NumPy, and Pandas provide some nice conveniences to do these things:

```
>>> import random
>>> import numpy as np, pandas as pd
>>> from itertools import product
>>> choices = 'RPS'
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((9,3)), columns=list(choices), index=[''.join(l) for l in product(choices, repeat=2)])
>>> user_choices = np.array([random.choice(choices) for _ in range(100)], dtype=str)
>>> agent_choices = np.array([random.choice(choices) for _ in range(100)], dtype=str)
for ac, cc in zip(agent_choices, np.char.add(user_choices, agent_choices)):
...     if ac == cc[-1]:
...         df[ac][cc] += 1
... 
>>> df
       R     P     S
RR  14.0   0.0   0.0
RP   0.0  14.0   0.0
RS   0.0   0.0   7.0
PR  11.0   0.0   0.0
PP   0.0  13.0   0.0
PS   0.0   0.0   8.0
SR  10.0   0.0   0.0
SP   0.0   8.0   0.0
SS   0.0   0.0  15.0
```

Since you seem to want it normalized to a percentage:

```
>>> df / 100
       R     P     S
RR  0.14  0.00  0.00
RP  0.00  0.14  0.00
RS  0.00  0.00  0.07
PR  0.11  0.00  0.00
PP  0.00  0.13  0.00
PS  0.00  0.00  0.08
SR  0.10  0.00  0.00
SP  0.00  0.08  0.00
SS  0.00  0.00  0.15
```

The obvious issue is this is always going to give you a sparse matrix. You're looking to count (user_choice, agent_choice) by agent_choice, then the only cells that can ever be filled in are those where the second char of the index matches the char of the column header. You may as well just collapse that to simply make the index and column header both ['R', 'P', 'S'] and count how many times a user chose 'R' when an agent chose 'R' etc.

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((3,3)), columns=list(choices), index=list(choices))
>>> for a, c in zip(agent_choices, user_choices):
...     df[a][c] += 1
... 
>>> df
      R     P     S
R  14.0  14.0   7.0
P  11.0  13.0   8.0
S  10.0   8.0  15.0
>>> df / 100
      R     P     S
R  0.14  0.14  0.07
P  0.11  0.13  0.08
S  0.10  0.08  0.15
```

You can see that contains the same information in a smaller matrix.